# Seria uma boa ideia criar a tag C#6?

Tags: debate, status-recusado, tags

Embora o C#6 já esteja ai e as "novidades" já não sejam tão novidades assim, as vezes eu vejo algumas perguntas que tratam especificamente de recursos que vieram com essa nova versão, [como essa aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91117/o-que-significa-o-simbolo-antes-de-uma-string).

Certamente temos outras e teremos mais. Então pensei que seria um boa ideia criar a tag C#6, mas decidi perguntar a opinião de vocês antes pois não quero "encher o site" com tags que não vão ser de utilidade nenhuma.

Comment: Acho melhor não, pega por exemplo a tag "java-8". Muitas perguntas não tem nada a ver com a versão 8 do Java, mas o AP inclui ela porque provavelmente quando ele digita "jav..." aparece um monte de sugestões. Na minha opinião a versão pode ser citada no conteúdo da pergunta **:D**

Comment: @renan essa é uma experiência importante. Dava até pra discutir se a *tag* citada deveria ser removida. Passado um tempo, não faz a mínima diferença se a *tag* está lá ou não. E muitas vezes a pessoa nem sabe se aquilo é de uma versão específica. A *tag* não irá adicionar nada relevante que ajude classificar de fato. É tudo parte da linguagem. Quando sair o C# 7, devemos ir lá colocar esta nova *tag*, afinal, também funciona na 7. Se a pessoa procurar por recursos existentes na 7, não vai achar as perguntas de recursos que foram criados na 6 mas existem na 7.

Comment: Eu acho que é tão raro a *tag* ser útil de verdade que não vale sua criação. É diferente marcar a versão da linguagem e a versão de uma tecnologia específica que muda muito mais. Estou menos favorável agora que vai se colocando mais informações.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Não

Apesar de concordar com @cigano a respeito da quantidade de novos recursos e achar os pontos mencionados válidos, eu gostaria de elaborar sobre alguns cenários:

- Como disse @bigown, eu acredito que usuários com dúvidas genéricas de C# irão utilizar a tag com maior frequência do que usuários com dúvidas legítimas de C#6, simplesmente porque eles utilizam VS2015 e a versão padrão de C# é 6 - mesmo que nenhum recurso da versão 6 esteja sendo utilizado ou presente na questão;
- Usuários de C# das versões anteriores não me parecem necessitar de tags específicas de versões;
- Nenhum comportamento de linguagem das versões anteriores foi refatorado, tornando assim desnecessário especificar se o trecho de código de uma versão específica é intencionado a rodar em C#5- ou C#6 (a versão pode ser inferida diretamente pelo código).

Comment: Bons argumentos.

Answer (score 7):

Ela serviria para indicar que algo é específico da versão 6. E provavelmente seria mal usada em perguntas comuns de C# e por acaso o AP está usando esta versão. Não acrescentaria nada nestes casos.

Em geral eu não gosto muito da ideia. Mas também não sou contra. Você vai analisar todas questões que tenha esta *tag* para ver se ela está usada corretamente? Aí aumenta a minha favorabilidade.

Comment: Se o jbueno, indivíduo, vai ou não analisar todas as questões com a tag não é relevante. Claro que é relevante que a comunidade interessada na tag C# faça isso. Só não se pode exigir que ninguém individualmente faça esse trabalho

Comment: Claro que não, nem exigi.

Comment: Eu não disse que você exigiu. Só quis deixar claro pra comunidade, porque o seu último parágrafo pode dar a entender isso.

Answer (score 4):

## Sim

[Não são poucos os novos recursos do C#6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6). Até então não o usei ele ainda porque o .NET 4.6 tem alguns problemas que ainda estão resolvendo ([pelo menos a nível de compilador](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2015/07/27/why-you-should-wait-on-dotnet-46/)).

Além de tratar de perguntas específicas sobre esses novos recursos, o Wiki pode ir na direção de prover não apenas informações como este artigo do GitHub que coloquei, mas também textos e códigos com outras aplicações ainda não colocadas.

Um exemplo que posso colocar isto como sendo útil é o caso das minhas tags favoritas: [asp.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) e [entity-framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework). Nas tags relacionadas, há as tags tecnológicas. Há perguntas e respostas que tratam especificamente de uma característica da versão, então considero pertinente a separação.

Comment: Então iria ser bom criar a tag **VB15**, que foi outra linguagem que recebeu novidades Roslyn?

Comment: A meu ver, não seria má ideia.